# Filter object properties matching interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some objects implementing some interfaces, but they also have extra properties.
When i come to serialize them (to save in a file), i would like to remove all thos extra properties, and keep only properties matching an interface.

Is there a way to "clean" an object regarding a given interface.
I was trying with

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject)
```

To get the full list of the object properties, and compare with the full list of the interface properties, but i cannot find a way to get the list of the interface properties

Edit : i found a way here : [How can I create an object based on an interface file definition in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142635/how-can-i-create-an-object-based-on-an-interface-file-definition-in-typescript)

With

```
var object = <IMyInterface>{};
```

But i saw that when i use Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject), this is working only for defined properties, if a property is not defined, it's not in the result. Is there a method to get all usable properties, not only the defined ones?

Comment: Can you post an example for properties?

Comment: for example for an Person object : name, surname, age, gender. And with an interface IPerson like : name, surname, age. I would like to be able to save my object excluding the "gender" property, as it's not in the interface

Comment: Interfaces don't exist at runtime so you can not do it. What you can do is to have a list per interface which consists of the properties names for that interface and then iterate over that at runtime

Comment: @NitzanTomer can you explain? i don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code:

```
interface MyInterface1 {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
}

interface MyInterface2 {
    field3: string;
    field4: string;
}

let o1 = {
    field1: "field1",
    field2: "field2",
    fieldN: "fieldN"
} as MyInterface1;

let o2 = {
    field3: "field3",
    field4: "field4",
    fieldN: "fieldN"
} as MyInterface2;
```

It compiles into:

```
var o1 = {
    field1: "field1",
    field2: "field2",
    fieldN: "fieldN"
};
var o2 = {
    field3: "field3",
    field4: "field4",
    fieldN: "fieldN"
};
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface1%20%7B%0D%0A%09field1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09field2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyInterface2%20%7B%0D%0A%09field3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09field4%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20o1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09field1%3A%20%22field1%22%2C%0D%0A%09field2%3A%20%22field2%22%2C%0D%0A%09fieldN%3A%20%22fieldN%22%0D%0A%7D%20as%20MyInterface1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20o2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09field3%3A%20%22field3%22%2C%0D%0A%09field4%3A%20%22field4%22%2C%0D%0A%09fieldN%3A%20%22fieldN%22%0D%0A%7D%20as%20MyInterface2%3B))

So you can see that in the compiled (js) code the interfaces do not exist, so you have no way of knowing (at runtime) what are the properties you need to keep.

What you can do is:

```
let myInterface1Keys = ["field1", "field2"];
interface MyInterface1 {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
}

let o1 = {
    field1: "field1",
    field2: "field2",
    fieldN: "fieldN"
} as MyInterface1;

let persistableO1 = {} as MyInterface1;
Object.keys(o1).forEach(key => {
    if (myInterface1Keys.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
        persistableO1[key] = o1[key];
    }
});
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20myInterface1Keys%20%3D%20%5B%22field1%22%2C%20%22field2%22%5D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20MyInterface1%20%7B%0D%0A%09field1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09field2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20o1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09field1%3A%20%22field1%22%2C%0D%0A%09field2%3A%20%22field2%22%2C%0D%0A%09fieldN%3A%20%22fieldN%22%0D%0A%7D%20as%20MyInterface1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20persistableO1%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20MyInterface1%3B%0D%0AObject.keys(o1).forEach(key%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(myInterface1Keys.indexOf(key)%20%3E%3D%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09persistableO1%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20o1%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(o1%2C%20persistableO1)%3B))

Comment: Yes i think this will work and this is my last choice as i would like not to have to create (and maintain) all those extra vars

Comment: If you can use a `class` instead of interface, then decorators can be used to do what you want.

Comment: instead of the object.key().foreach you can you pick from lodash : `persistableO1 = _.pick(o1, myInterface1Keys)`

Comment: this is old, but it picks properties from object, not from interface. Even though I know there really isn't a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In late 2023, is it yet possible to do this kind of reflection in TypeScript? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77588045/470749

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented using the `keyof` operator in conjunction with `Object.keys()` to extract the keys of an object that match the properties defined in an interface:

```
interface IMyInterface {
  property1: string;
  property2: number;
}

function cleanObject<T>(obj: T, interfaceRef: T): T {
  const interfaceProperties = Object.keys(interfaceRef) as Array<keyof T>;
  const objectProperties = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;

  objectProperties.forEach(property => {
    if (!interfaceProperties.includes(property)) {
      delete obj[property];
    }
  });

  return obj;
}

const myObject = { property1: 'value1', property2: 2, extraProperty: 'extraValue' };
const cleanedObject = cleanObject(myObject, <IMyInterface>{});

console.log(cleanedObject);
// Output: { property1: 'value1', property2: 2 }
```

Basically, `cleanObject` is a generic function that takes in an object `obj` and an interface reference `interfaceRef`.

The `Object.keys()` method is used to extract the keys of `obj` and `interfaceRef` and convert them into arrays. The `keyof` operator is used to ensure that the arrays contain **only keys that match the properties of the respective object or interface**.

Finally, a loop is used to compare the properties of `obj` with the properties defined in `interfaceRef`. If a property in `obj` is not present in `interfaceRef`, it is deleted from `obj`.

The cleaned object is then returned as the result of the function.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I really like @Nitzan's answer, but one issue I have run into is that the keys that are hard-coded into the string array do not update when I update my types, leading to errors that would otherwise be caught by typescript. So I recommend typing the array of key strings too, so that typescript prompts you to update it as well, should you later change your types:

```
interface MyInterface1 {
    field1: string;
    field2: string;
}

let o1 = {
    field1: "field1",
    field2: "field2",
    fieldN: "fieldN"
} as MyInterface1;

let myInterface1Keys: Array<keyof MyInterface1> = ["field1", "field2"]; //<--------

let persistableO1 = {} as MyInterface1;
Object.keys(o1).forEach(key => {
    if (myInterface1Keys.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
        persistableO1[key] = o1[key];
    }
});
```

Answer (score -7):

You can do like following:

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.person = {
    name : "John",
    surname : "Doe",
    age : 50,
    gender : "male"
 };
});

app.filter("myfilter", function(){
  return function (input, excludeItem) {
    delete input[excludeItem];
    return input;
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Solutions-1</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in person | myfilter:'gender'">{{key}} : {{value}}</div>
    </div>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/Asit124/pen/ZOWJeM