# How to export TypeScript types as object to expose which keys are available

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if the following is possible in TypeScript.

Here is a much simplified version of my code:

```ts
export type CustomEmailPayload = Record<string, string>;

interface BaseLessonPayload extends CustomEmailPayload {
  teacherGivenName: string;
  lessonDate: string;
}

interface ReminderPayload extends BaseLessonPayload {
  chatUrl: string;
}

interface FollowUpPayload extends BaseLessonPayload {
  reviewYourTeacherUrl: string;
}

export type EmailTemplateParameters = {
  Reminder: ReminderPayload;
  FollowUp: FollowUpPayload;
};
```

Over time, I'll add to and remove from `EmailTemplateParameters`.

I want there to be a simple way to print out a mapping of which parameters are available in which email types.

I.e. I want to export an object like:

```ts
{
  Reminder: ['teacherGivenName', 'lessonDate', 'chatUrl'],
  FollowUp: ['teacherGivenName', 'lessonDate', 'reviewYourTeacherUrl'],
}
```

That way, the non-engineers who are writing transactional emails in HubSpot know which custom properties are available for the type of email they're editing.

Comment: So do you want to get a type of the shape that you've included or a real json?

Comment: @wonderflame Real JSON. From all of my searching so far, it seems quite difficult to do this kind of reflection in TypeScript. But it feels ridiculous for me to need to manually write out a nested object by hand (and then keep it in sync over time). All of the information is derivable from my types.

Comment: Perhaps you can modify the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222224/print-typescript-types-into-console-file) to meet your needs

Comment: @wonderflame That looks very interesting! I'll check it out next week. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [A2A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909566/get-keys-of-a-typescript-interface-as-array-of-strings/59806829?noredirect=1#comment136783531_59806829).

You can turn each of the Payload interfaces into a **class** and use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806829/2321594).

To be specific:

```js
abstract class BaseLessonPayload {
  constructor(readonly teacherGivenName?: string, readonly lesssonDate?: string) { }
}

class ReminderPayload extends BaseLessonPayload {
  constructor(readonly chatUrl?: string) { super(); }
}

class FollowUpPayload extends BaseLessonPayload {
  constructor(readonly reviewYourTeacherUrl?: string) { super(); }
}

console.log({
  Reminder: Object.keys(new ReminderPayload()),
  FollowUp: Object.keys(new FollowUpPayload()),
});
// ^^^ output:
// {
//    Reminder: ["teacherGivenName","lesssonDate","chatUrl"],
//    FollowUp: ["teacherGivenName","lesssonDate","reviewYourTeacherUrl"],
// }

// ~~~ For the Email Templates: ~~~

class EmailTemplateParametersClass {
  constructor(
    readonly Reminder = new ReminderPayload(),
    readonly FollowUp = new FollowUpPayload(),
  ) {}
};

interface EmailTemplateParameters extends EmailTemplateParametersClass {};
// ^^ can be exported

const testParams: EmailTemplateParameters = {
  Reminder: { chatUrl: "x", teacherGivenName: "t1", lesssonDate: "ld1", },
  FollowUp: { reviewYourTeacherUrl: "r1", teacherGivenName: "t1", lesssonDate: "ld1", },
}; // compiles properly!

const paramsInstance = new EmailTemplateParametersClass();
const paramsMap: Record<string, string[]> = {};
Object.entries(paramsInstance).forEach(([key, value]) => { paramsMap[key] = Object.keys(value); });

console.log(paramsMap);
// ^^^ output:
// {
//    Reminder: ["teacherGivenName","lesssonDate","chatUrl"],
//    FollowUp: ["teacherGivenName","lesssonDate","reviewYourTeacherUrl"],
// }
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAQwRgzgLgTiDGUAE8A2IISQIQwUwBk9MB7AOwAUQBPVEkAEyQG9gkVzoYBXREmABQw8jcqmpIoI%20AAs8MAOIBLAG54yAORABbPAH4AXEi5KyAcwA0SYaLLikqYqTIAREFMPHYpswEoWSAC%20wMHAaBhYAEp42qYM8lS09Ex4AB5SZAxYuBCETuSJdIwsbBxkXLxQ-EIiDGISsu4AqjConibm-szG3AAO8gK%20ANxBIcBh6JhIAGIkqHQA7k29hclIaRlZOPhEzqvFrOzwnLCV1TZ1dhLCKkp4CwCaJNwwACrScjAtbUYdfgEQPoDYajULHcpzPAAOjoZgEhyQ0VimXkRgA8mAAFZ4RBQgDWeGoEAEZHuiJicQSNCKDEGvgspVm8xIS166KxOKg%20MJxNJCxmc0Wy32tN89JCw2AAHopUhnlBetwoAZpbLWDL2OwkZSYEYANoAIikCE%20yjUmh0eANFgNjkwEHIbik1oNjSg3wNAF0GRrNUyhWykIbjbJ5Gb1FpdC67c4nVabTc7o9nm8PvIPd7VaMswA-PMCmCSORIACi2hASlQSHe2l66CkECMeZz43CUzLFdQNbr7jwVDguikMAgAGFJlgEeCKnxBKV2Bd6uTkfFCwBeJB8pc6kWDBma6y1Rf%20lnLJDrzfH1k78XsLrBQJDcamIcAMwQeFL5cr3frfZAA7wIcsA2dQtg7b8Yh7KR%200tICxwiFgHyzAA9ZCUBAMgkDAD80l6fgpAYVsTkkYgoBg7RG0-Tsf17cjAPkLB1wRbUUV1AI3W%20IwDVSa0SJNMNVAjS0uKgABGXiYwdVxey41AGHEqxAj3AVmVZIxukTe4nhed5%20K%20VouJgBS%20NDRRBItXQROMyTHRkpBbXk3ilJCEYNWOWtK2IJBehgEh%20laagAEIiPKZBen-HQIAASVCjD4A-c8yXArtIN-Oi4PHQZHynMKIoogBZEBA2iY4YAYAAeP4rD%20PVPQAPjPRDHwxbFcXUbxiAEcKB2i2KyHi3woRffgSxNAQBD1AlqCsFQQFQbg8E9fxVwa7pusiwrekmwlPUalrOW5IkBFm%20a8BBQJJTCThIRhEg4XWgqiuGDV5UVZUs3VWVNRYld9SNNMzPNSN41tJwpLjF0ONaL0fS%209hL2WP6Q1NczgejMHbOdBM8FuLSU100yM1h0YgA)

PS. I'd personally vote for having an inheritable/overridable `getParamKeys(): string[]` function in the base and sub classes.  Yes, it would require you to rewrite the names of the keys twice (at least in proper places), but it would be more flexible than these optional readonly constructor properties.

Comment: This is amazing!! Thank you! It's true that I don't want the properties to be optional. Making them optional would allow us to accidentally write code where we're not sending all the required data to HubSpot. Is your PS saying that you know a way of making them required? But it involves me writing the properties twice? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, what I'll explore is whether I can define type EmailTemplateParameters programmatically from paramsMap, setting each string as a required property.