# How to generate a type dynamically from object or classes

Tags: typescript

I have TS objects like:

```ts
const myObject = {
   AdminInviteStudent:  ['inviterGivenName', 'inviterFamilyName', 'link'],
   DeleteMappingStudent: ['teacherGivenNameAndInitialOfFamilyName', 'studentGivenName', 'noteLink']
};
```

What is a TS function to export a type based on that object?

I want to pass that object as an argument like this:

```ts
export type EmailTemplateParameters = getType(myObject);
```

All of the array values should be set as required strings.

In this case, the EmailTemplateParameters result should be:

```ts
{
  AdminInviteStudent: {
    inviterGivenName: string;
    inviterFamilyName: string;
    link: string;
  };
  DeleteMappingStudent: {
    teacherGivenNameAndInitialOfFamilyName: string;
    studentGivenName: string;
    noteLink: string;
  };
}
```

Or maybe there is a better way to enhance the answer to my original question: [How to export TypeScript types as object to expose which keys are available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77588045/470749)

Comment: You can't have a "function" to do that but you can have a generic type: https://tsplay.dev/WKrdGm

Comment: Why do you need a utility at all? It isn't going to be any less typing than specifying `myObject` using `as const` and a simple alias `export type Foo = typeof myObject;`. If the `readonly`-ness is an issue then the playground by katniss should suffice. There's no way for a function to operate on types because they have no runtime reification, they "compile away".

Comment: @katniss Thanks for that quick answer! That's the right idea, but when I use that, it's still allowing me to write `const templateData: EmailTemplateParameters["trashInput"]` and not throwing an error about "trashInput". And even if I correctly write `const templateData: EmailTemplateParameters["AdminInviteStudent"]`, it still lets me set templateData as an object missing what should have been required string properties. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for your response. `myObject` is really coming from https://stackoverflow.com/q/77588045/470749 so can't be a `const`, I don't think. Maybe I shouldn't be using classes as suggested by the answer to that question? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan I don't think using a class has anything to do with it in this case. I *think* the problem is (don't have enough data to be certain) that you are tilting with windmills on this: you are asking for a DWIM shortcut that probably doesn't exist (katniss' solution is probably about as close as you can get). There are just too many ambiguities in trying to extract a type from an object. You are most likely going to have to define an explicit type/interface and live with the minor duplication in the type and the value.

Comment: I... don't see any of those issues you described with the playground: https://tsplay.dev/w2QxbW Did you implement it incorrectly? You could keep using the classes but you would need to tack on assertions to assert them as `(keyof ReminderPayload)[]` etc. and that requires more duplication... I honestly don't know why they suggested you create classes out of this. You could've just gone "reverse" and derive the types themselves from the object, instead of deriving the object from the types (which is not possible). My playground is essentially doing the former.

Comment: @katniss Thanks. I came to that conclusion just now too, and that's what I'll try. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @katniss This was the way to go! Thanks for your help!! You're amazing. If you post an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step would be to annotate `myObject` with `as const` so that the string values are "preserved" as literal types.

```
const myObject = {
   AdminInviteStudent:  ['inviterGivenName', 'inviterFamilyName', 'link'],
   DeleteMappingStudent: ['teacherGivenNameAndInitialOfFamilyName', 'studentGivenName', 'noteLink']
} as const;
```

Then, if we have a type to map over an object and the arrays to create a new type:

```
type GetType<T extends Record<string, readonly string[]>> = { // allow readonly arrays
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: { // remove readonly modifier
    [P in T[K][number]]: string;
  }
};
```

We can pass the type of (`typeof`) `myObject` to it and get the right result:

```
export type EmailTemplateParameters = GetType<typeof myObject>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDCQIIAmcAlmAJJgBuVUGAylAK7kZhQBcJANoByGkxYAnAOJUGPAHIBDOBmEAaGKMbMMEgGLKqAGwRKV6zUZoBrYQF01xEgBEMRjCwCyigA4+aAObsXDz8MCIsisAAFroycmBmGKRg5PTMVIpGSABmBtQmSRbC0CG88QrKqhrCYCAsADI29oQAvjCKEDCgkFAA3ISEUAg+GDBSHgAqIxgAPJMwGAAeLKldAEpYIBLks9ASgRoSGIrk4CYw+4GCdgB8tzB4RCQAtMen5wjhANIwNDDWDAIEA5GCTOwCZ4kcIABT+YDBgm+dkEYA4cBQujsEMuUAOYACAxIrTaA0Iyx821gw1GMAAonBFMZJhg4D4jIoWDDFBIqpIungJlBpqNZjSMCD4Mh0FgoLcBgB6BXQlXQgB6AH4gA)

---

Addressing the previous question, you should instead derive the type from the object, not the object from the type (which is not possible):

```
type CreateType<Keys extends readonly string[]> = { [K in Keys[number]]: string };

type AdminInviteStudent = CreateType<typeof myObject["AdminInviteStudent"]>;
```

Comment: I was finally allowed to give you a bounty! I really appreciated your quick, helpful comments and answer!