# Form not displaying with empty form fields as part of the create CRUD process in Angular 7 application

Tags: angular

I am creating create functionaltiy which is part of CRUD operation for one of my model in angular 7 application. I am using template driven forms. As you can see I have temporarily set the ManagerId to 0 to initiate the Create. As you can also see in my html , I am only displaying the contents if the ManagerDetails is not null.
At the moment I am getting blank form. How I show blank fields on the screen.

```
import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ManagerService } from '../services/manager.service';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { CommonDataService } from '../services/common.data.service';
import { IManager } from './manager.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-manager',
    templateUrl: './manager.component.html'
})


export class ManagerComponent implements OnInit {

    private Error: string;
    public ManagerDetails: any;
    public EditMode: boolean;
    public Editor = ClassicEditor;
    public EditorConfig: string;
    @Input() ManagerId: number;

    constructor(private managerService: ManagerService, private commonDataService: CommonDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ManagerId = 0;
        if (this.ManagerId !== 0 ) {
            this.getManagerDetails();
        } else {


        }
    }

    getManagerDetails() {
        if (this.ManagerId != null) {
            this.managerService.getManagerDetails(this.ManagerId).subscribe((data: IManager[]) => {
                this.ManagerDetails = data;
            });
        }
    }

    saveManager() {

        if (this.ManagerDetails.ManagerId === 0) {
            this.managerService.createManager(this.ManagerDetails).then((result ) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.getManagerDetails();
                    this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                }
            });

        } else {
            this.managerService.updateManager(this.ManagerDetails).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.getManagerDetails();
                    this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

html

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Manager Details</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input
                    type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div *ngIf="ManagerDetails" class="card-body scrollClass" style="width:100%">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label modal-label header">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerDetails.FirstName}}</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerDetails.FirstName" />
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label modal-label header">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{ManagerDetails.LastName}}</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="ManagerDetails.LastName" />
                </div>


            </div>



        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">

            <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                    (click)="saveManager()">Save</button>

            </span>
            <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                    (click)="cancelManager">Cancel</button>
            </span>
            <span><button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all"
                    (click)="deleteManager()">Delete</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to create an empty object model

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142635/how-can-i-create-an-object-based-on-an-interface-file-definition-in-typescript, see the code `const modal = {} as IModal;`