# Why does the function requires two arguments if it already has them inside an object?

Tags: typescript

I am currently learning Typescript and I am getting an error that doesn't quite make sense to me.

The following function `addId` has an object as an argument

```js
const addId = <T extends object>(obj: T) => {
  const id = Math.random().toString(16)
  return {
    ...obj,
    id,
  }
}
```

There also is an `interface` that has two generic types.

```js
interface UserInterface<T, V> {
  name: string;
  data: T;
  meta: V;
}
```

Now, I create an object called `user` that takes an object and a string.

```js
const user: UserInterface<{ meta: string }, string> = {
  name: 'Jack',
  data: {
    meta: 'foo',
  },
  meta: 'bar'
}
```

When I call the function `addId` it throws the following error: `Generic type 'UserInterface<T, V>' requires 2 type argument(s).`.

```js
const result = addId<UserInterface>(user)
console.log('result', result)
```

I do not understand why I have this error since the `user` object has `name`, `data` and `meta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what are you trying to achieve with that user declaration above?
But seems to me that your problem lies in `<UserInterface>(user)`, the compiler is expecting two arguments for the interface!
Why not [implement the interface through a class and create a user object using that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142635/how-can-i-create-an-object-based-on-an-interface-file-definition-in-typescript)?

UPDATE:

try to make the call like this: `const result = addId(user)` instead of const `result = addId(<UserInterface>(user))`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I am just following [the example from this video](https://youtu.be/gp5H0Vw39yw?t=4957) but it seems that that example might not make sense in the 'real world'.

Comment: Okay. try to make the call like this:
`const result = addId(user)` instead of `const result = addId(<UserInterface>(user))`